# Insert XHTML content in JSP file

Tags: jsp, insert, xhtml

I have to insert an XHTML content into my JSP file, but I don't know how to do it. Someone told me, that I have to use p:view tag, but the question is the same: how?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can paste a file into a JSP servlet during translation using the include directive:

```
<%@include file="includee.xhtml" %>
```

Comment: It can be possible to insert this XHTML content into <div> tag anywhere in JSP file?

Comment: Yep, you can use the include directive anywhere in the JSP file.

Comment: Opps... I forgot something... this XHTML file contains Primefaces content

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience with JSF or PrimeFaces. And from what I've read, JSF has a rather poor reputation within the web development community, so I wouldn't advise you to use it. So with respect to including content in a JSP page, I can't give you any detail on JSF/PrimeFaces requirements/idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another approach, you can also use tag files. These are more powerful than JSP include directives because they allow argument passing from the including JSP or tag file to the included tag file. Here's an example:

WEB-INF/tags/namespace/head.tag:

```
<%@attribute name="name" required="true"%>

<script type="text/javascript" src="blah.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">.class1 { color:${name}; }</style>
```

home.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@taglib prefix="namespace" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/namespace"%>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <namespace:head name="red"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="class1">red div</div>
</body>

</html>
```